# I Want to Upload a File Using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the code below to upload file-

**Code:**

```
app.post('/file_upload',  function(req,res){
    console.log('FIRST TEST: ' + JSON.stringify(req.files.theFile.name));
    console.log('second TEST: ' +req.files.theFile.name);
    fs.readFile(req.files.theFile.path, function (err, data) {
        var newPath = "/tmp/"+req.files.theFile.name;
        var fileName = req.files.theFile
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
          res.send("hi");  
        });
    });
});
```

and i am getting **Error:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined

Please guide me how to solve this.

Comment: do you want to upload a file, or receive a file? Please post the part of your code that contains the error.

Answer (score 3):

According to your codes posted in your question, it is hard to figure out the root cause of `error`. Here is one sample to upload file which I used before, please try it.

```
app.post('/upload/create', function(req, res){  
    //save the upload file to folder tmp/  
    var tmppath = req.files.file.path;  
    var targetpath = '/tmp/'+req.files.file.name;  

    fs.rename(tmppath, targetpath, function(err){  
        if (err) throw err;  

        fs.unlink(tmppath, function(){  
          if (err) throw err;  

          console.log('upload file successfully...');  
      });  
  });
```